# "Ask question" button displaced

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design

On my Linux, Chrome 14 shows the main page like this:
[image]

Comment: Clearly the problem in Linux.  You should use a bug free OS like Windows instead :P

Which version of Chrome?

Comment: @JohnGB Good call, in fact this is Chromium (14.0.835.163). Yet Firefox 6.0.2 does the same.

Comment: possibly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33090/slight-rendering-bug-in-chrome-linux-view-count-and-title-overlap/33110#33110

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty old post.  I'm sorry it didn't get any response when it was posted, but lots of CSS changes have happened since then.  I'm resolving this, but if it's still a problem feel free to update the post.

Comment: Yeah, for some time I haven't seen this problem so it is likely resolved.